# ClassInfo function in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rtti

When I define a class like this in **Delphi 7**:

```
  TPerson = class(TObject)
  private
    FLName: string;
    FFName: string;
    FAge: integer;
    FBDate: TDate;
  public
  published
    property FName: string read FFName write FFName;
    property LName: string read FLName write FLName;
    property Age: integer read FAge write FAge;
    property BDate: TDate read FBDate write FBDate;
  end;

procedure ListComponentProperties(AObject: TObject; Strings: TStrings);
var
  Count, Size, I: Integer;
  List: PPropList;
  PropInfo: PPropInfo;
  PropValue: string;
begin
  Count := GetPropList(AObject.ClassInfo, tkAny, List);
  Size  := Count * SizeOf(Pointer);
  GetMem(List, Size);
  try
    Count := GetPropList(AObject.ClassInfo, tkAny, List);
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      PropInfo := List^[I];
      PropValue := VarToStr(GetPropValue(AObject, PropInfo^.Name));
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(List);
  end;
end;
```

and I want to get a list of its published properties with ListComponentProperties an error message will be displayed.The error is related to the following command and **AObject.ClassInfo**:

```
Count := GetPropList(AObject.ClassInfo, tkAny, List);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In future when you ask a question relating to an error message, please include the error message in your question, quoted verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable RTTI for that type. By default it is not enabled. Declare the type like this:

```
type
  {$M+}
  TPerson = class(TObject)
  ....
  end;
  {$M-}
```

Your initial call to `GetPropList` is also wrong. It must read:

```
Count := GetPropList(AObject.ClassInfo, tkAny, nil);
```

If you enabled warnings the compiler would have told you that you were passing an uninitialized variable.

I've not checked any more of your code. There may be more errors.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible enable RTTI in Application level Once and for all?

Comment: No. Best you can do is derive from a $M+ type

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `$M` compiler directive, you can derive your classes from any class that has RTTI info enabled.

One of such classes is [TPersistent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TPersistent) that should be used as base class for any class that needs to have assignment and streaming capabilities.

> TPersistent encapsulates the behavior common
>   to all objects that can be assigned to other objects, and that can
>   read and write their properties to and from a form file (.xfm or .dfm
>   file).
>
> Do not create instances of TPersistent. Use TPersistent as a
>   base class when declaring objects that are not components, but that
>   need to be saved to a stream or have their properties assigned to
>   other objects.

In practice that means that if you want to use `TPerson` class as published property of some component that can be edited in IDE via Object Inspector and streamed to form file (`.dfm`) your class must have `TPersistent` as ancestor in it's class hierarchy.

```
type
  TPersonComponent = class(TComponent)
  protected
    FPerson: TPerson;
    procedure SetPerson(AValue: TPerson);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Person: TPerson read FPerson write SetPerson;
  end;

constructor TPersonComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FPerson := TPerson.Create;
end;

destructor TPersonComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FPerson.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPersonComponent.SetPerson(AValue: TPerson);
begin
  FPerson.Assign(AValue);
end;
```

If you use class declared as `TPerson = class(TObject)` in above example, its properties (even though published and with RTTI information turned on) will not be saved into `.dfm` file when `TPersonComponent` is edited in Object Inspector.